# .save returns false when I try to save in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, activeadmin

I have this transaction:

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    route_array.each do |r|
      Rails.logger.info r.save 
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see I have the `route_array` and I'm trying to save it in the database, but `r.save` returns `false` and I have no clue why. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The main raison is your model RouteArray has some validations which are not respected.

You can try this code :

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
   route_array.each do |r|
     if !r.valid?
       Rails.logger.info r.errors.inspect
     else
       Rails.logger.info r.save 
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it goes into the else and show me this:
false
false
false
false
false
false.......

Comment: maybe you wanted to mean if !r.valid? Rails.logger.info r.errors.inspect

Comment: Ooops, it was !r.valid. Now you can have the errors of your model.